# ¿Cómo iterar a través de un HashMap?

Tags: java, hashmap

Tengo una estructura en HashMap y necesito iterarla a través de un `for`. Como puedo hacer esta iteración?

Mi código:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Testeo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<Integer, String> datos = new HashMap<>();
        datos.put(1, "uno");
        datos.put(2, "dos");
        datos.put(3, "tres");

        //necesito iterar aquí
    }
}
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Si usas Java 8 puedes aprovechar las expresiones lambda para escribir un código compacto:

```
datos.forEach((k,v) -> System.out.println("Key: " + k + ": Value: " + v));
```

No hay necesitad de usar `EntrySet`, los tipos de dato de `k` y `v` son inferidos automáticamente.

Comment: Muy buena opción. Quizás el único inconveniente es que requiere Java 8.  No obstante, Oracle ya descontinuó las actualizaciones gratuitas para Java 7 hace tiempo, pero muchas empresas siguen utilizando incluso Java 1.4.

Comment: Tienes toda la razón, aunque de ser posible hay que usar las nuevas versiones para no seguir estancando nuestro código.

Comment: ¿Qué es una expresión lambda?

Comment: @TripleX es básicamente una sintaxis más corta para expresar una función o método en Java

Comment: Y si el value del HashMap es un ArrayList por ejemplo, y quiero acceder a uno de sus atributos? X.X

Answer (score 18):

No hay forma de iterar sobre el HashMap directamente, pero se puede iterar sobre el [`entrySet()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#entrySet--)

Por ejemplo:

```
Map<Integer, String> datos = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
datos.put(1, "uno");
datos.put(2, "dos");
datos.put(3, "tres");

for (Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry : datos.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println("clave=" + entry.getKey() + ", valor=" + entry.getValue());
}
```

Fuente: [Stack Overflow (en inglés)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3344768/135050) por [Jesper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/135589/jesper)

Comment: Un voto negativo inexplicable, al menos para mi. ¿Alguien podría explicar que hay de errado en esta respuesta? Funcionó perfectamente para mi.

Comment: Me parece que hay un error en  map.entrySet() remplazarlo datos.entrySet()

en Android Studio da "warning" lo de new HashMap<Integer,String>() mejor HashMap<>();

Comment: @Webserveis Tienes razón, quedó corregido. Gracias!

Comment: @Webserveis depende de la versión de Java que utilices. Para Java 5 y 6, ese código compila, para Java 7 y superior, ese código también compila pero puede ser reducido utilizando el operador diamante `<>`, y lo que te muestra el IDE no es un warning de compilación sino un warning de optimización de código (propio del IDE)

Answer (score 10):

Link de referencia: [How to Iterate Over a Map in Java](http://www.sergiy.ca/how-to-iterate-over-a-map-in-java)

Hay varias formas de iterar sobre un mapa en java. Vamos a ver los metodos mas comunes y a revisar sus ventajas y desventajas. Debido a que todos los mapas en java implementan la interfaz `Map`, las siguientes tecnicas te van a servir para cualquier implementacion de `Map` (`HashMap`, `TreeMap`, `LinkedHashMap`, `Hashtable`, etc.)

**Metodo #1: Iterando sobre las entradas usando For-Each.**

Es el mas comun y el mas preferible en la mayoria de casos. Se suaria en el caso que necesites tanto valor como key.

```
Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println("Key = " + entry.getKey() + ", Value = " + entry.getValue());
}
```

Nota que el ciclo For-Each fue introducido en Java 5 por lo tanto solo funciona en las primeras versiones de java. Tambien el ciclo `For-Each` arrojaria `NullPointerException` si intentas iterar sobre un mapa `nulo`, por lo tanto siempre hay que revisar antes por referencias `nulas`.

**Metodo #2: Iterando sobre las keys o values usando una ciclo For-Each.**

Si solo necesitas o las keys o los values peudes usar `keySet` o `values` en lugar de `entrySet`.

```
    Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

    //iterating over keys only
    for (Integer key : map.keySet()) {
        System.out.println("Key = " + key);
    }

//iterando solo sobre valores
for (Integer value : map.values()) {
    System.out.println("Value = " + value);
}
```

Este método da una leve ventaja en performance sobre la iteracion `entrySet`  (cerca de 10% mas rapida) y es mas limpia.

**Metodo #3: Iterando usando `Iterator`.**

Usando Genericos:

```
Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
Iterator<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>> entries = map.entrySet().iterator();
while (entries.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry = entries.next();
    System.out.println("Key = " + entry.getKey() + ", Value = " + entry.getValue());
}
```

Sin Genericos:

```
Map map = new HashMap();
Iterator entries = map.entrySet().iterator();
while (entries.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry entry = (Map.Entry) entries.next();
    Integer key = (Integer)entry.getKey();
    Integer value = (Integer)entry.getValue();
    System.out.println("Key = " + key + ", Value = " + value);
}
```

Tambien puedes usar la misma tecnica para iterar sobre `keySet` o `values`.

Este metodo puede parecer redundante pero tiene sus ventajas. Primero que todo es la unica manera de iterar sobre mapas en versiones mas viejas de java. Otra caracteristica importante es que este es el unico metodo que te permite remover entradas del mapa durante la iteracion usando `iterator.remove()`. Si intentas hacer esto con una iteracion For-Each  obtendras "resultados inpredecibles" de acuerdo con JavaDoc.

Desde el punto de vista del performance esta es lo mismo que una iteracion For-Each.

**Metodo #4: Iterando sobre keys y buscando los values (ineficiente).**

```
Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
for (Integer key : map.keySet()) {
    Integer value = map.get(key);
    System.out.println("Key = " + key + ", Value = " + value);
}
```

Esta pareceria ser una alternativa mas limpia del metodo #1 pero en la practica es muy lenta e ineficiente obteniendo values por key podria consumir mucho tiempo (este metodo en diferentes implementaciones de `Map` es 20%-200% mas lento que el metodo #1). Si tienes [FindBugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/) instalado, lo detectara y te avisara de una iteracion ineficiente. Este metodo debe ser evitado.

**Conclusion:**

Si solo quieres los keys o los values usa el metodo #2. Si estas atorado en alguna version vieja de java (menor a 5) o planeas remover las entradas durante la iteracoin usa el metodo #3. De cualquier otra manera usa el  #1.

Comment: Con closures y haces de tu respuesta la más completa, aunque creo que es la más completa hasta ahora.

Comment: No entiendo con qué fin añades código sin genéricos en esta respuesta. Que estamos en 2016, ha llovido mucho.

Comment: A veces uno tiene que lidiar con código heredado antiguo y no te queda más remedio que ajustarte a lo que hay. Para esos casos es útil saber cómo trabajar sin genéricos.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo

Answer (score 5):

El interfaz `Map` (implementado por `HashMap`) tiene el método [entrySet()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#entrySet%28%29) el cual devuelve una vista del Map como `Set`. Y los `Set` son iterables :

```
    for ( Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry : datos.entrySet() )
    {
        System.out.println("Clave=" + entry.getKey() );
        System.out.println("Valor=" + entry.getValue());
    }
```

Ten en cuenta que el `Set` devuelto por `entrySet()` no es una copia. Está respaldado por el `Map` con lo que todos los cambios que en uno se hagan afectarán al otro.
Esto también significa que, en caso de aplicaciones multi-hilo, has de tener cuidado de no modificar el `Map` mientras iteras el `Set` de esta manera.

Answer (score 4):

También es posible *iterar* una instancia de [`java.util.Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) con la ayuda del método [`keySet`](http://bit.ly/1UOLcP6). Este método devuelve una instancia de [`java.util.Set`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html), la cual es una vista del mapa. Cualquier cambio sobre ésta afectará al mapa.

- *Código*:

  ```java
  for (int key : datos.keySet()) {
      System.out.printf("Clave=%d, Valor=%s%n", key, datos.get(key));
  }
  ```
- *Salida*:

  ```
  Clave=1, Valor=uno
  Clave=2, Valor=dos
  Clave=3, Valor=tres
  ```

Comment: Esta es una muy buena respuesta. Por que no tiene mas votos?

Answer (score 3):

En mi opinión, en muchas ocasiones el siguiente código me resulta más intuitivo y práctico:

```
HashMap<Integer, String> datos = new HashMap<>();
datos.put(1, "uno");
datos.put(2, "dos");
datos.put(3, "tres");

for (String dato : datos.values()) 
{   System.out.println(dato);
    ...
}
```