# Cómo recorrer la colección de un <objeto> y un <objeto)>

Tags: java

> Si yo deseo recorrer colecciones en un HashMap: `HashMap<Integer, Elemento>`) lo recorrería con un `foreach()` ademas si implemento un `Iterator()` no entiendo muy bien los dos formas de recorrerlo. No encuentro la diferencia ni sus funciones de cada uno para recorrer lo que quiero recorrer.

**Elemento.java**

```
package stackoverflowejemplo;

public class Elemento {

private int numeros;
private String nombre;

public Elemento(int numeros,  String nombre){
    this.numeros = numeros;
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

public int getNumeros() {
    return numeros;
}

public void setNumeros(int numeros) {
    this.numeros = numeros;
}

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}
public String toString(){
    return getNombre() +" - "+getNumeros() ;
    }
    }
```

**Mapa.java**

```
import java.util.HashMap; import java.util.Iterator; import java.util.Map.Entry;

 public class Mapa {

      public static void main(String[] args) {

       HashMap<Integer, Elemento> map  = new HashMap<>();
       map.put(1,new Elemento(2,"hola"));

       //foreach    

    } }
```

Comment: Me es difícil seguir la pregunta. Por favor pon el código de las dos formas que dices que usarías.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aseguro que los elementos que imprimo tienen un método `toString()`. Luego este `foreach` te asegura que si tienes un método `toString()` en la clase `Elemento.java` en el cual,  recorrerás así el objeto `valor` con la ayuda de la `llave(Key)`.

```
map.keySet().stream().forEach((llave) -> {//expresión lambda
            System.out.println(map.get(llave));
        });
```

**ó así:**

```
for (String llave : map.keySet()) {//foreach clásico
    System.out.println(map.get(llave));
    }
```

Luego un iterator pude echarle un vistazo [aquí](http://migranitodejava.blogspot.com.es/2011/06/iterator.html) para entender su funcionamiento y la expresión lambda se describe [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/2464/c%C3%B3mo-iterar-a-trav%C3%A9s-de-un-hashmap/2473) con claridad.

Answer (score 3):

Primero que nada, en Java no existe `for-each()` como en otros lenguajes. Lo que existe en Java desde Java 5 es [`enhanced for-loop`](https://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/using_enhanced_for_loops_with). Esta sentencia, detrás de las escenas, lo que hace es usar un iterador para recorrer la colección (en el caso de arreglos no es necesario usar un iterador).

El siguiente código que usa enhanced for-loop:

```
public void imprimir(List<String> lista) {
    for (String string : lista) {
        System.out.println(string);
    }
}
```

Java lo traduce luego a:

```
public void imprimir(List<String> lista) {
    for (Iterator<String> it = lista.iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
        String string = it.next();
        System.out.println(string);
    }
}
```

Si quieres crear una clase que pueda funcionar con el enhanced for-loop, no basta con que tu clase/interfaz provea un método que permita obtener un `Iterator`, sino que **debe** implementar la interfaz [`Iterable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html). Aquí un ejemplo (muy simplificado):

```
public class MiListaSimple implements Iterable {
    private static class Node {
        int dato;
        Node sig;
    }
    private Node cabeza;

    public void agregar(int dato) {
        Node nuevo = new Node();
        nuevo.dato = dato;
        nuevo.sig = cabeza;
        cabeza = nuevo;
    }

    private class MiIterador implements Iterator<Integer> {
        private Node actual;
        public MiIterador(Node actual) {
            this.actual = actual;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return actual.sig != null;
        }

        @Override
        public Integer next() {
            Integer resultado = actual.dato;
            actual = actual.sig;
            return resultado;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<Integer> iterator() {
        return new MiIterador(cabeza);
    }
}
```

Con la clase anterior, puedes usar el siguiente código:

```
MiListaSimple lista = new MiListaSimple();
lista.agregar(3);
lista.agregar(2);
lista.agregar(1);
for(Integer dato : lista) {
    System.out.println(dato);
}
```

Salida:

```
1
2
3
```

Comment: Una pregunta. ¿[`Stream#forEach`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#forEach-java.util.function.Consumer-) no se consideraría como equivalente a un foreach en otros lenguajes como por ejemplo, JavaScript?

Comment: @GustavoGarcía sí pero considera que ese es un método, no una sentencia con palabras reservadas. Además, ese método solo es válido para streams, mientras que el `enhanced for-loop` sirve para arreglos y para cualquiera que implementa `Iterable` y está disponible en Java 5, 6 y 7 donde no existen los streams.

Comment: Genial. Muchas gracias por la aclaración.

Comment: Pero como recorro esa colección que he puesto, no no me sale, me sale un código hexadecimal.

Comment: Necesito ver el código que usas. Además, asegura que los elementos que imprimes tienen un método `toString`.