# Comparar valores entre dos HashMap

Tags: java, android, hashmap

Tengo dos `HashMap` en mi código

```
  HashMap<Long, Double> partesTrabajoIdHorasDb = new HashMap<>();//ID+horas
  HashMap<Long, Double> partesTrabajoIdHorasLocal = new HashMap<>();
```

El primer `Hashmap`

> partesTrabajoIdHorasDb

guarda dos valores `key = id` y `valor = horas_totales_trabajo_remoto`

En el segundo `HashMap`

> partesTrabajoIdHorasLocal

tiene el mismo formato 
`key = id` y `valor = horas_totales_trabajo_local`

Lo que tengo que hacer es buscar las coincidencias de id entre los dos HashMap y una vez encontradas sumar ambos valores es decir en pseudocodigo :

```
if (TrabajoIdHorasDb.id == partesTrabajoIdHorasLocal.id)
horas totales = horas_totales_trabajo_remoto + horas_totales_trabajo_local
```

Alguien me puede decir que hacer para encontrar los `id` comunes entre ambos `HashMap` y sumar los valores para esos ids?

Comment: Revisa como iterar :   https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/2464/c%C3%B3mo-iterar-a-trav%C3%A9s-de-un-hashmap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si deseas obtener las key que coinciden entre 2 `HashMaps` y sumar sus valores puedes realizarlo de esta forma:

```
    for (Map.Entry<Long, Double> entry1 : partesTrabajoIdHorasDb.entrySet()) {
      Long key = entry1.getKey(); 

      //Compara los key si son iguales.                   
      if(partesTrabajoIdHorasLocal.containsKey(key)){

      //si son iguales obtiene los valores.
          Double value1 = entry1.getValue();
          Double value2 = partesTrabajoIdHorasLocal.get(key); 
        System.out.println ("El key es igual : " + key + " las horas totales son: " + (value1 + value2));            

      }
    }
```

Como iterar y encontrar coincidencia en key entre 2 HashMap. Agrego un [ejemplo completo](https://www.ideone.com/cFt9jE) :

```
    Map<Long, Double> HashMap1 = new HashMap<>();
    HashMap1.put(1L, 12.2);
    HashMap1.put(2L, 22.1);
    HashMap1.put(3L, 14.5);
    HashMap1.put(4L, 11.9);
    HashMap1.put(5L, 34.5);
    HashMap1.put(6L, 24.7);

    Map<Long, Double> HashMap2 = new HashMap<>();
    HashMap2.put(10L, 12.1);        
    HashMap2.put(11L, 14.4);
    HashMap2.put(2L, 18.9);
    HashMap2.put(14L, 19.5);
    HashMap2.put(29L, 12.5);


    for (Map.Entry<Long, Double> entry1 : HashMap1.entrySet()) {
      Long key = entry1.getKey();                    
      if(HashMap2.containsKey(key)){
          Double value1 = entry1.getValue();
          Double value2 = HashMap2.get(key); 
        System.out.println ("Se encontro similar key con valor : " + key + " el valor sumado es: " + (value1 + value2));            
      }
    }
```

Comment: que grande eres !!! muchas gracias

Comment: @JoCuTo te sugiero revises https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/2464/c%C3%B3mo-iterar-a-trav%C3%A9s-de-un-hashmap para que entiendas más este proceso, saludos!